# Xcode 7 error "dyld: Library not loaded"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, aubio

I'm using the aubio audio library in my iOS app. Its been compiling fine in Xcode 6.3. Since updating to Xcode 7 i've been trying to debug this error that occurs on device on app startup.

I'm using aubio version 0.4.2, iOS universal framework.

> dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libaubio.4.dylib
>     Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/3263665E-C6B5-4B86-9AAF-C6A783A5ED80/MyApp.app/MyApp
>     Reason: image not found

If I set aubio as an optional framework it loads the rest of the app but then crashes on the first call to aubio, in my case `new_aubio_pitch()`

I thought it might be to do with Bitcode, so turned it off and still get the error.

I've also tried adding the framework to "Embedded Binaries", as well as adding it to the "Copy files build phase"

The project contains Swift files, in case that could be affecting it.

Comment: Are you adding the library in the link build phase?  What if you remove it and add it again?  Also, can you verify there's a valid file at that path (`/usr/local/lib/libaubio.4.dylib`)?

Comment: Yes I can verify that there is a valid file at that path on my system. I also removed and readded the framework to the "Link Binary with Libraries" section within the target's Build Phases. Still get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem.  Downgrading to Aubio 0.4.1 solved it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that aubio version 0.4.2 had been compiled as a dynamic not a static library. Communication with the author has resulted in the new 0.4.2 build being built as a static library so it now works as expected.